# How to override values inside fastlane's appfile using .env files

Tags: ios, fastlane

We have the need to override values in fastlane's appfile in certain situations, e.g. to use a different apple account for publication of the app, but there is no documented official way.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is using environment variables:

Use an `Appfile` like this:

```
apple_id ENV["APPLE_ID"] || "default@company.com"
app_identifier ENV["APP_IDENTIFIER"] || "com.company.default"
```

When you now call [fastlane](https://fastlane.tools) without environment variables:

```
fastlane beta
```

it will use the default values provided (`default@company.com`)

to set a different value you can use

```
APP_IDENTIFIER="com.custom.app" fastlane enterprise
```

Also as already pointed out by other replies, you can always have multiple lanes for different environments and just pass a different app identifier or username to each of the actions you're calling.

Comment: Combining this with the --env parameter seems to be the most comfortable way to do this

Comment: Yas! Thank you, very helpful!

Answer (score 5):

We found a way to do this, using a ignored .env file in the main project folder.

It can be used to override values in the appfile as follows:

```
require('dotenv')
Dotenv.load '../.env'

app_identifier "original.app.identifier" # The bundle identifier of your app
apple_id "account@example.com" # Your Apple email address
team_name "originalTeamName"
team_id "originalTeamID"

unless ENV["N42_FASTLANE_APP_IDENTIFIER"].nil?
  app_identifier ENV["N42_FASTLANE_APP_IDENTIFIER"]
end

unless ENV["N42_FASTLANE_APPLE_ID"].nil?
  apple_id ENV["N42_FASTLANE_APPLE_ID"]
end

unless ENV["N42_FASTLANE_TEAM_NAME"].nil?
  team_name ENV["N42_FASTLANE_TEAM_NAME"]
end

unless ENV["N42_FASTLANE_TEAM_ID"].nil?
  team_id ENV["N42_FASTLANE_TEAM_ID"]
end
```

New values van be set in the .env file as follows:

```
N42_FASTLANE_APPLE_ID="anotherAccount@example.com"
```

Comment: I think `Dotenv.load ` isn't necessary, fastlane supports .env files natively. You should just run it with `--env` parameter. E.g. you have a `.env.Production` file. Then you can run fastlane like `fastlane <lane_name_here> --env Production`.

Comment: You're welcome) It's not well documented, but it's mentioned [here](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/fastlane/docs/FAQs.md) in the "Multiple targets" section.

Answer (score 1):

The `Appfile` has support for overriding values for different lanes: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/fastlane/docs/Appfile.md.

You can also specify different `team_id`s, `username`s and `app_identifier`s in your `Fastfile`, for example:

```
lane :example_lane do
cert(
      username: "email@company.com",
      team_id: "ABCDE123"
    )    
sigh(
      username: "email@company.com",
      team_id: "ABCDE123",
      app_identifier: "com.company.example.app"
      )
gym(
      export_team_id: "ABCDE123"
      ) 
end
```

Comment: We knew about this way, but wanted to overwrite exactly one value (per machine) without having a "dirty" Appfile in git and without having a multitude of lanes.