# Use fastlane supply with dotenv

Tags: android, ios, fastlane

#### Context & example configuration

In order to set up fastlane for the first time in a project, I define different **.env** files, which I'd like to use with dotenv as described in [in fastlane's FAQ](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/fastlane/docs/FAQs.md#multiple-targets-of-the-same-underlying-app).

Example **.env.dev** file:

```
JSON_KEY_FILE="/home/sam/.keys/googleplay/magnet.json"
```

In my **Appfile** I reference it using **ENV**, as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37329477) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38261924) Stack Overflow answers:

```
# Path to Google Developer Console key
json_key_file ENV["JSON_KEY_FILE"]

# Package name of the project. If not included in the environment, default value is used.
package_name ENV["PACKAGE_NAME"] || cl.magnet.androidfastlanetest
```

#### My problem

I can't get past the ["Fetch your app metadata" step of fastlane's setup](https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/android/setup/#fetch-your-app-metadata), as I get an error when running `fastlane supply init` with the `--env` option:

```
~/repos/android-fastlane-test|master⚡ ⇒ fastlane supply init --env dev
undefined local variable or method `cl' for #<CredentialsManager::AppfileConfig:0x005560049ed220>
undefined local variable or method `cl' for #<CredentialsManager::AppfileConfig:0x005560049e2eb0>
undefined local variable or method `cl' for #<CredentialsManager::AppfileConfig:0x005560055588f8>
undefined local variable or method `cl' for #<CredentialsManager::AppfileConfig:0x005560055368c0>
undefined local variable or method `cl' for #<CredentialsManager::AppfileConfig:0x0055600551a698>
undefined local variable or method `cl' for #<CredentialsManager::AppfileConfig:0x005560054fe6f0>
undefined local variable or method `cl' for #<CredentialsManager::AppfileConfig:0x005560054e6b18>
invalid option: --env
```

What am I doing wrong? Given that I need to keep the path to `JSON_KEY_FILE` not in **Appconfig**, but in a separate file, what should I do?

Comment: Where did you define the `cl` object you reference in your `Appfile`?

Comment: @KrauseFx, my **Appfile** consists only of the two lines shown in the question. The `cl` reference is in the package name line: `package_name ENV["PACKAGE_NAME"] || cl.magnet.androidfastlanetest`

Comment: The `undefined local variable..` was just I was missing quotation marks in the package name, anyway I still have the `invalid option: --env` problem

Comment: Close this question then or auto-answer your question please

Answer (score 0):

Fastlane actions does not support the --env variable like the lanes does.

To workaround the issue, simply source the env file before running your action command:

```
source fastlane/.env.custom; bundle exec fastlane supply init
```

For this to work you would need to specify your env variable like so (in the env file):

```
export FLAVOR=Dev
```